# How can I make the bot ignore other actions made my other bots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to know how I can make the bot ignore other bots actions (role update, removed) and stop logging them. Here is my code:

```
    let messagechannel = oldMember.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === config.logsChannel);
    if (!messagechannel) return 'Canalul respectiv nu există!'

    if (oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#383b3d')
            .setDescription(`${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.user}) a fost actualizat.`)
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.user.tag}`, oldMember.user.avatarURL)
            .addField(`ID`, oldMember.id)
            .setFooter(`${bot.user.tag}`, bot.user.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp();

        for (const role of newMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {
            if (!oldMember.roles.has(role)) {
                embed.addField(`Schimbări`, "➕    " +  `${newMember.guild.roles.get(role)}`);
            }
        }
        messagechannel.send(embed);
    }

    if (oldMember.roles.size > newMember.roles.size) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#383b3d')
            .setDescription(`${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.user}) a fost actualizat.`)
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.user.tag}`, oldMember.user.avatarURL)
            .addField(`ID`, oldMember.id)
            .setFooter(`${bot.user.tag}`, bot.user.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()

        for (const role of oldMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {
            if (!newMember.roles.has(role)) {
                embed.addField( `Schimbări`, "❌   " + `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role)}`);
            }
        }
        messagechannel.send(embed);
    }

    if (newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname) {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#383b3d')
            .setDescription(`${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.user}) a fost actualizat.`)
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.user.tag}`, oldMember.user.avatarURL)
            .addField(`ID`, oldMember.id)
            .addField(`Numele vechi`, `${oldMember.displayName}`)
            .addField(`Numele nou`, `${newMember.displayName}`)
            .setFooter(`${bot.user.tag}`, bot.user.avatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()

        messagechannel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Can someone help me? I dont know much about these thing so I little code might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to archive this with minor changes to your existing code.
The `User` property of `GuildMember` (newMember/oldMember) has a property `bot`
that returns a Boolean if that user is a bot user or not.

So what you could do is at this `if (oldMember.user.bot || newMember.user.bot) return`
to the very top of the code you just sent.
More information about the `bot` property you can find [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot)